# Rails app missing web.1 log on Heroku logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a rails app deployed on the Heroku server. When I view the logs using "heroku logs --tail", the logs didn't include the [web.1] logs such as GET PUT method information

```
2015-08-13T05:42:38.561579+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-    512839984b0409ab29d0db41a487a0a7a7e25c9bf0d7ff275ac4b7a502bb84c4.js" host=steam-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=88893db0-14e0-490f-b3d9-5c189fcf7768 fwd="128.250.0.10" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=17ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-08-13T05:43:13.820739+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/ftp_servers/new" host=steam-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=6119d69e-ba37-404a-af4c-1fc022b1d08f fwd="128.250.0.10" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=144ms status=200 bytes=7683
2015-08-13T05:43:26.811633+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/import" host=steam-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=8d0c021e-26ad-41c7-9fa1-e1fa33cdc930 fwd="128.250.0.10" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=27ms status=401 bytes=903
2015-08-13T05:43:27.149431+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/import" host=steam-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=1d4eea1a-1bad-4ead-9eaa-4a4a827114e8 fwd="128.250.0.10" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=84ms status=200 bytes=2326
2015-08-13T05:43:33.835192+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users/import" host=steam-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=db08e749-116d-4ad0-ab1c-92d35b365472 fwd="128.250.0.10" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=83ms status=500 bytes=1754
```

However, my another app can show the [web.1] logs, looks like

```
2015-08-13T03:51:41.013118+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=stephensample.herokuapp.com request_id=2f6f71a9-bca9-4b7c-8d35-cae752e94282 fwd="128.250.0.10" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=228
2015-08-13T03:51:58.913419+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 128.250.0.10 at 2015-08-13 03:51:58 +0000
2015-08-13T03:51:59.047547+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (1.7ms)
2015-08-13T03:51:59.047614+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (64.1ms)
```

What's wrong with my first app? I have errors on my first app but I cannot see the logs.

Comment: Could you post `config/environments/production.rb` for both of your app's?

Comment: Both of the apps include `production.rb`, and I compare the two, the content is the same

Comment: Show us please the content of this files.

Comment: The content is added on the topic

Comment: Did you include [rails_12factor](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor) gem in your production environment?

Comment: Yes, I didn't include the rails_12factor gem. After adding it, the log works, thanks!

Comment: @nayiaw post it as an answer, i to want upvote it.

Comment: added my formal answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include [rails_12factor](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor) gem to allow logging on Heroku. Note that if your application production server is no longer using Heroku you'll have to remove it, otherwise the logging may not work on other servers(happened to me a few times).

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check production log file using this

```
$ heroku run rails c
File.open('log/production.log', 'r').each_line { |line| puts line }
```

Comment: this doesn't provide an answer to the OP question.

Comment: In production file we will know how exactly errors are there

Comment: The output only includes one line: `=> #<File:log/production.log>`